# jQuery cannot trigger a click on a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a link in the view:

```
<small><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="morelink">Show more</a></small>
```

And it's event is handled in jQuery:

```
$("#morelink").click(function () {
    $('#displayDiv').show;
    return false;
});
```

And I want to trigger a click on the link after I hit any button in the `editBtn` class:

```
$('.editBtn').on('click', function () {
     $('#morelink').trigger('click'); // not triggered
});
```

How ever the link is not triggered in IE or Chrome. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Your click handler does nothing so not sure what you are expecting...  `$('#displayDiv').show`?!  `$('#displayDiv').show();`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax Error. See [docs of `.show()` here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Change

```
$('#displayDiv').show;
```

to

```
$('#displayDiv').show();
```

```js
$("#morelink").click(function() {
  $('#displayDiv').show();
  return false;
});
$('.editBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#morelink').trigger('click'); // not triggered
});
```

```css
#displayDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="morelink">Show more</a></small>

<button class="editBtn">Edit A</button>
<button class="editBtn">Edit B</button>
<button class="editBtn">Edit C</button>
<div id="displayDiv">DISPLAY DIV</div>
```